# Cant click menu items in Garrys Mod on Linux

Tags: linux, garrys-mod

I installed a fresh copy of Garrys Mod on Ubuntu (newest version) and i also installed some other games like Half Life 2.

Now I want Garrys Mod to load maps and other contents from the other games. In Windows, I had to click the small controller in the right bottom corner. But when I click it, the menu doesn't freeze but does not react to any input anymore.

The background still rotates and chages pictures and workshop addons keep downloading. The game does not crash, but I can't click anything anymore and no menu is shown at all (I wanted to get to the list of other games i have in my steam collection).

I can change the gamemode and I can change the language. So it must be a problem with the first button!

[image]

Is this a known issue? I can't find anything about it. I already tried reinstalling it again. Same problem.

Comment: Try right-clicking on Garry's Mod in the Steam menu, click "Properties", and you should see something that say "Verify Integrity" or something like that. Click it and when it finishes, try Garry's Mod again.

Comment: I already tried that at the time i asked this question. I have had many problems with ubuntu in steam games that i didnt have in windows. I switched back to windows and this fixed my issue. I even reinstalled ubuntu with a fresh downloaded image and I had the same problems again. I just think ubuntu is not usable for games...